# Is there a kind of include once in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have `FileA`, `FileB` and `FileC`.

`FileA` includes `FileB` and `FileC`.
`FileC` includes `FileB`.

Is there an kind of include-once functionality in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: So why you include `File B` from `File A` explicitly?

Comment: @Flack File B could be view as a library

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution for your inclusion problems -- simply use `<xsl:import>` instead of `<xsl:include>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **[`<xsl:import>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#import)** instead of **[`<xsl:include>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#include)** there would be no error.

**As the W3C XSLT 1.0 specification says**:

"It is an error if a stylesheet directly or indirectly imports itself. Apart from this, the case where a stylesheet with a particular URI is imported in multiple places is not treated specially."

Comment: Visual Studio Intelisense does not find <xsl:import />

Comment: ok I found, it must be the first child of the <xsl:stylesheet />

Comment: @Christophe-Debove: `<xsl:import>` instructions should immediately follow the `<xsl:stylesheet>` instruction -- probably you missed to follow that rule. VS imposes this rule by not prompting for an `<xsl:import>` at places where it must not occur.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the redundant xsl:include directives so each module is included only once. FileC does not need to xs:include FileB, even if it references components in FileB.

Comment: ok, all the references are loaded in memory but VisualStudio cannot do the link (or pre-reference) so there is a lot of errors. The transormation is going right. but it's difficult to developp with a lot of red on the screen