# Set of xslt with duplicate information

Tags: .net, xslt

I have a lot of `xslt` files which sometimes contain totally duplicate information of some the same object. Is there a possibility to carry it to another `xslt` and include it inside the existing ones? How to do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`<xsl:include>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-include)** helps modularize XSLT code, but doesn't itself remove duplicate code.

**One the most fundamental feature of XSLT -- [templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-template) -- if used properly, can significantly eliminate any code duplication**:

1. The match pattern of a template matches different types of nodes on which the template is to be applied -- this eliminates duplication when the same code is used in many places when processing different instances of the same match pattern. While a template can be invoked similarly to a function/subroutine using **[`<xsl:call-template>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-call-template)**, it is much more powerful and flexible to select a matching template for processing using **[`<xsl:apply-templates>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-apply-templates)** -- the latter resembles calling a virtual function off a base type in OOP -- we don't know what derived objects will be existing at the time of execution and which of the possibly many specializations (overrides) of the corresponding virtual function, would be selected for execution.
2. The above technique, combined with *passing parameters* to a template helps eliminate duplicate code where only some values/nodes are different.
3. Using templates one can simulate Higher Order Functions (HOF) and pass a template/function as a parameter to another template/function and return a template function as the result of applying a template/function. New functions can be created dynamically using functional composition and partial application. The FXSL library implements HOFs for both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.
4. In the coming XPath 3.0 / XSLT 3.0 HOFs are a standard feature of the language. Functions can be passed as parameters and returned as results to/of other functions. Anonymous (inline) functions can be created dynamically within an XPath 3.0 expression. The new standard XPath 3.0 functions `fold-left()`, `fold-right()` and `map()` are the most fundamental functions typically used in any functional programming language. Their use allows to significantly reduce code size and code duplication.

Comment: very nice explanation; personally I have used <xsl:include> only for long lists of needed variables; +1

Comment: @Peter, Yes, XSLT templates and pattern matching are a very poweful feature -- typically missing in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of `<xsl:include>`
Have a look at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/11/01/xslt/index.html or
[Is there a kind of include once in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219101/is-there-a-kind-of-include-once-in-xslt)